# Access violation writing location using dynamic array

Tags: c++

I'm working on a big project and I can't get passed this problem. I'm sure it's some syntax I'm overlooking. I've simplified it down to this problem in my code below. I created a dynamic array in one function, but it will not pass in the return function. I'm getting the Access violation writing location, so I know its something to do with pointing of the dynamic array. I've been coding for 36 hours, so any advice would help greatly.

Header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H        
struct process {
    int thing1;
    int thing2;
};
class join {
private:
int something;
int something2;
process * p;
public:
    join();
    void SetT(int);
    void SetP();
    void returnP();
};
#endif // !Header_h
```

Header.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
join::join() {
    something = 0;
    something2 = 0;
}
void join::SetT(int ST) {
    something = ST;
}
void join::SetP() {
    process * p = new process[something];
}
void join::returnP() {
    p[1].thing1 = 12;       //error occurs
    cout << p[1].thing1;
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    join j;
    j.SetT(2);
    j.SetP();
    j.returnP();
}
```

Comment: `process * p = new process[something];` is not referencing the class' version of p, it is creating a new one local just to that function

Comment: How would you go about making it global for the class?

Comment: @MichaelDennis Stop using 1-letter variable names and start to use descriptive names.  Your issue is one big case why using variables named `p`, `o`, etc. will get you in trouble.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wrote it really fast to illustrate the problem I'm running into. Thank you for the input though.

Comment: `p = new process[something];` is how. Though, you'd want to do some check around it to make sure it's not already set, which would require you actually initializing it to NULL/nullptr in the constructor.

Comment: @PhilM Ok, I'm stupid! I've been staring at a computer for way too long. thank You!